# How to firebase hosting rewrites set to source except for images?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want rewrite to functions, except for images, or except for "** /. *".
But I could not find how to write Globs in firevase.json.
Please tell me how to write

This code did not work.

```
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "!(**/.*)",
        "function": "frontend"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks!
I solved it by myself.

this code working!

in firevase.json

```
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "!**/*.@(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)",
        "function": "app"
    }
],
```